# Error Passing Variables Between Stacks with Serverless Compose: Issue with serverless-sequelize-migrations Plugin

Tags: plugins, serverless-framework

I am trying to pass variables between stacks using Serverless Compose, but I get an error when running a custom script to execute a sql migration using the serverless-sequelize-migrations plugin.

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.DB_PORT": The param "dbport" cannot be resolved from CLI options or stage params. If you are using Serverless Framework Compose, make sure to run commands via C
ompose so that all parameters can be resolved
Error:
Error: Command failed: serverless migrations down
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:957:15)
    at Scripts.execute (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless-plugin-scripts/lib/index.js:113:35)
    at Scripts.runHook (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless-plugin-scripts/lib/index.js:108:12)
    at PluginManager.runHooks (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:530:15)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
    at async PluginManager.invoke (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:564:9)
    at async PluginManager.run (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:604:7)
    at async Serverless.run (/Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless/lib/serverless.js:179:5)
    at async /Users/christoffer/Documents/code/konsult-gpt/node_modules/serverless/scripts/serverless.js:834:9
```

The variable is usable in the stack as I can see it in my environment when deploying a lambda. Is there something I am missing about how serverless handles its context or is this maybe a bug in the plugin?

Relevant snippets from my setup:

serverless_compose.yml:

```
services:
  service:
    path: service

  migration:
    path: migration
    params:
      dbport: ${service.port}
```

service/serverless.yml:

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    port:
      Value: 3306
```

migration/serverless.yml:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-sequelize-migrations
  - serverless-plugin-scripts

Provider:
  environment:
        DB_PORT: ${param:dbport}

functions:
  myLambda:
    handler: org.MyHandler
    memorySize: 2048
    timeout: 20

custom:
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:deploy': serverless migrations down
```

Answer (score 0):

> The passing of parameters from the service stack to the migration stack works fine, as evidenced by my lambda being deployed by the migration stack has the value.
>
> The issue is that the plugin trying to use the same value cannot resolve it.

Given that the framework can correctly resolve the variables (as demonstrated by the successful deployment of your Lambda function), it suggests the script that is being run by `serverless-plugin-scripts` does not have access to the resolved variables in the same way.

A possible workaround could be to pass the environment variable directly in the custom script command, rather than relying on the plugin to resolve it correctly.

Try and modify the `custom.scripts.hooks` section in your `migration/serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
custom:
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:deploy': serverless migrations down --DB_PORT ${self:provider.environment.DB_PORT}
```

The `DB_PORT` variable is passed directly to the `serverless migrations down` command as a CLI option, using the `${self:provider.environment.DB_PORT}` syntax to refer to the environment variable defined in the same `serverless.yml` file.

---

> Unfortunately, it seems like the plugin does not allow variables to be passed that way as I get the following error: "`Detected unrecognized CLI options: "--DB_PORT"`"

Since the plugin does not allow for passing environment variables through CLI options, a workaround would be to create a script that sets the environment variable at the system level before invoking the `serverless migrate down` command ([`npm install serverless-migrate-plugin`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-migrate-plugin)).

Add the plugin to your serverless.yml:

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-migrate-plugin
```

Create a script named `run_migrations.sh` (executable: `chmod +x`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export DB_PORT=$(serverless print --path provider.environment.DB_PORT --stage $1)
sls migrate down
```

Update your `migration/serverless.yml` to use this script in the custom scripts hooks section:

```yaml
custom:
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:deploy': ./run_migrations.sh ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```

That way, the script fetches the `DB_PORT` variable from the Serverless Framework configuration using the [`serverless print` command](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/print), and then exports it as a system environment variable before running the `sls migrate down` command.
The stage is passed as a parameter to the script to ensure the correct variable value is fetched based on the stage you are deploying to.

---

If that is still not working, as an alternative approach, you might consider writing a script to manually extract the necessary parameter and set it as an environment variable before invoking the `serverless migrations down` command.

For instance, creating a Node.js script that reads the Serverless Framework's output to extract the necessary variable and then invokes the migration command with the correct environment variable.

Try and create a `runMigration.js` script:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('serverless compose param list -o json', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Execution error: ${err}`);
    return;
  }

  try {
    const params = JSON.parse(stdout);
    process.env.DB_PORT = params.dbport;
    exec('serverless migrations down', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Execution error: ${err}`);
        return;
      }

      console.log(`Output: ${stdout}`);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Could not parse output', e);
  }
});
```

The `serverless compose param list -o json` command should list all the compose parameters in JSON format.
We then parse this output to extract the `dbport` parameter, setting it as an environment variable.
And we execute the `serverless migrations down` command with the correct environment variable.

Next, update the `custom.scripts.hooks` section in your `migration/serverless.yml` file to use this script:

```yaml
custom:
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:deploy': node runMigration.js
```

That involves more manual management of the environment variables, but it could help to bypass the limitations you are encountering with variable resolution in the Serverless Framework.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood, the passing of parameters from the service stack to the migration stack works fine, as evidenced by my lambda being deployed by the migration stack has the value.
  
The issue is that the plugin trying to use the same value cannot resolve it.
  
Thinking about this a bit more I think it might be the plugin not using the context of serverless for the variables, but looking at the serverless file itself being incapable of resolving it, but that is just me speculating.

Comment: @user2270439 OK, that is clearer. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the plugin does not allow variables to be passed that way as I get the following error: "Detected unrecognized CLI options: "--DB_PORT"."

I'll make an issue on the plugins github page.

Comment: Sadly that approach runs into the same issue as before:
`Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.DB_HOST": The param "dbhost" cannot be resolved from CLI options or stage params. If you are using Serverless Framework Compose, make sure to run commands via C
ompose so that all parameters can be resolved`

I am going to look for a different approach at this point, thank you so much for your efforts.